# Handling files with whitespace in their names

Tags: bash, shell, find, filenames

I have a lot of files that I need to sift through, specifically grep for certain keywords IN THE FILE, not he FILENAME.  I have some 300+ files on a filesystem (so the files are within multiple different directories) and some have white space in their names.

when I search for filed using find

```
find -type f
```

and print the results, some of the file names go on different lines WHICH IS NOT GOOD.

How can I handle

Answer (score 3):

Some implementations of the `grep` command like GNU `grep` can recurse directories on their own. If you're looking for string "blahblah" you can do this:

```
$ grep -r "blahblah" .
```

This will `grep` through all the files and directories recursively starting at the current directory, `.` (beware that some implementations, like old versions of GNU `grep` will also follow symbolic links when descending the directory tree). That will show you the file names and the result that matched the search pattern, one per line. If you just want the filenames without the matching content add the `-l` switch to `grep`.

```
$ grep -rl "blahblah" .
```

If you really want to use `find` you can make use of `find`'s ability to execute  commands against the files that it finds, using the `-exec` switch.

```
$ find . -type f -exec grep "blahblah" {} +
```

The `+` at the end is key, since it will determine the optimal number of filenames that `find` locates, and call `grep` loading the command-line with as many as will fit. These filenames will be placed where the braces are, `{}`. It's easier to visualize what it's doing, if we substitute in the `echo` command in `grep`'s place you'll hopefully see what I mean.

#### Example

Say I had the following sample data.

```
$ mkdir -p dir{1..3}
$ touch file{1..3}
$ touch dir{1..3}/file{A..C}
```

Now when I run the above `find` command using `echo` as our `grep` stand in:

```
$ find . -type f -exec echo {} +
./file2 ./file1 ./dir2/fileA ./dir2/fileB ./dir2/fileC ./dir3/fileA ./dir3/fileB ./dir3/fileC ./file3 ./dir1/fileA ./dir1/fileB ./dir1/fileC
```

All those files were echoed to the screen by a single `echo` so this method is very efficient at only calling `echo` or `grep` only the minimum number of times that are needed, passing as many filenames as it can to each.

By using `-type f` above, we're only searching in *regular* files, while `grep` would generally look in every file like fifos, sockets, devices (but not necessarily symlinks)... You can pass a `-D skip` option to some versions of `grep` to avoid looking into devices/sockets/fifos.

Comment: I made an edit. I should have been more specific, sorry.

Comment: @user2840647 - all my answers are grepping through the file content, not the names!

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep yourstring
```

The `-print0` option to find,  as well as its `-0` pendant to xargs, use the null-byte as separator meaning your file names can be anything you like and there will be no surprises.

The actual problem is that the internal file separator of the shell (stored in the IFS variable) is a space. You could change it to be a newline or whatever you like but the real solution is to use what I showed above.